# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY backward compatibility

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY.
I am able to make a build from  eclipse but when I try to use commond line gradle I get compilation error.

symbol:   variable SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
  location: class View
  ..\ListActivity.java:240: error: cannot find symbol
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

Thanks,
Manan

Answer (score 0):

In your build file you need to supply latest platform jars as dependencies. To do that first you need to deploy platform jars to your local maven repo.

Here is an example for maven conf on Windows. Run this under your sdk folder

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=platforms/android-19/android.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=android -Dversion=19 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=platforms/android-19/android-sources.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android -DartifactId=android -Dversion=19 -Dclassifier=sources -Dpackaging=jar
```

And in the dependencies section just use the dependency

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
     <artifactId>android</artifactId>
     <version>19</version>
</dependency>
```

You may want to use a version number scheme that android version and not the platform version but I like this.